# md-autocomplete doesn't update on first click

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

I finally got md-autocomplete working in my Angular4 app but it doesn't show the options when you first click on the list (like it does in the [demo](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)) - it only shows it once the selection changes.

This is my html:

```
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Assign Artist" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="userCtrl">
  </md-input-container>

  <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" [value]="user" 
      (onSelectionChange)=selectUser(user)>
        {{ user }}
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

And my component:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userCtrl = new FormControl();

    this.filteredUsers = this.userCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith('')
        .map(name => this.filterUsers(name));
  }

  filterUsers(val: string) {
    if (this.users === undefined) return;

    return val ? this.users.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) == 0 && this.selectedUsers.includes(s) == false)
               : this.users.filter(s => this.selectedUsers.includes(s) == false);
  }
```

UPDATE:

I've added a plunker. It's now almost there, the only issue I have now is that when I select a user I would like the list to remain visible but just show the new filtered list (without the selected user). Currently it doesn't update even if I click on the input again. I have to type something, then delete it to update the filtered list...

https://plnkr.co/edit/hcy1x2QIePChhbdhXbTs?p=preview

Comment: Please create a plunker

Comment: Hi Faisal, i've added a plunker above

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `ngOnInit()` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
Observable.from(this.options)
          .toArray()
          .subscribe(users=>{
  this.users = users;
  this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .startWith(null)
    .map(user => user && typeof user === 'object' ? user.profile.name : user)
    .map(name => this.filter(name));
});
```

In this case your users collection will contain data when you set `filteredOptions`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the class below, works 90% of the times:

```css
.mat-option-text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

why?:
inside mat-option component there is a span element with mat-option-text class.
I suppose the event should trigger on the mat-option component.
so we want to ignore click event on that span element